# How do I stop a loop from indefinitely looping in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, do-while

I have this try/catch wrapped around a do/while loop because after the try/catch throws the error message, I want it to loop back to the top. I tried do/while, while, and I tried placing the while loop at different places in my code but nothing works. The program works fine until an exception is thrown and then it goes into an infinite loop. After is displays the error message, I just want it to loop back up to the top.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    Integer userInput;
  do {
   try{ 
    System.out.print("Enter a number? \n");
    userInput = input.nextInt();

      if ( userInput == 1 )
         Animal1.displayMessage ();//Display the total
      if( userInput == 2 )
         Animal2.displayMessage ();//Display the total

      }
       catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" That's not right ");
        break;

      }
      } while (true);
      }
```

}

This is what it does after displaying an error message.

```
    Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
 That's not right 
Enter a number? 
Enter a number?
```

If I don't stop it, it just keeps going.

Comment: I have a lot of indefinite loops, myself.  I should really work on making them more certain.

Comment: This works properly, as you described, for me.

Comment: I just tested your code. It loops infinitely if I enter a number, but it terminates the loop as it should if any other input is entered.

Comment: as @oscarbcn shows you need to consume the `<CR>` that has been entered by doing `input.next();`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this workaround:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    Integer userInput;
  do {
   try{ 
    System.out.print("Enter a number? \n");
    userInput = input.nextInt();

      if ( userInput == 1 )
         Animal1.displayMessage ();//Display the total
      if( userInput == 2 )
         Animal2.displayMessage ();//Display the total

      }
       catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" That's not right ");
        input.next();

      }
      } while (true);
      }

}
```

or if you want to avoid try-catch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Integer userInput = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number? \n");
            if (input.hasNextInt())
                userInput = input.nextInt();
            else {
                System.out.println(" That's not right ");
                input.next();
            }
            if (userInput == 1)
                Animal1.displayMessage ();//Display the total
            ;// Display the total
            if (userInput == 2)
                Animal2.displayMessage ();//Display the total

        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the input.next(); is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can give 3 options - one option to exit

```
System.out.print("Enter a number? \n 1 to display Animal1 total\n2 to display Animal2 total\n 3 to exit");
```

Inside while loop, you can add

```
if ( userInput == 3) break;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the try/catch statements outside of the loop.